# Shell file doesn't extract value properly [grep/cut] from file [bash]

Tags: bash, shell, grep, sh, cut

I have a `test.txt` file which contains key value pair just like any other property file.

**test.txt**

```
Name="ABC"
Age="24"
Place="xyz"
```

i want to extract the value of different key's value into corresponding variables. For that i have written the following shell script

**master.sh**

```
file=test.txt
while read line; do
  value1=`grep -i 'Name' $file|cut -f2 -d'=' $file`
  value2=`grep -i 'Age' $file|cut -f2 -d'=' $file`
done <$file
```

but when i execute it; it doesnt run properly, giving me the entire line extracted by the `grep` part of the command as output. Can someone please point me to the error ?

Comment: Why do you have another $file in the end of the cut command? Leave it away. You already get the specified line from the grep command, through the pipe. It could look like value1=`grep -i 'Name' $file|cut -d'=' -f2    Pay attention to the grep -i command. Ignore case. If the character combination age or name appears in a value, your grep command might return 2 lines.

Comment: no it is returning only one line.. but after removing the $file  too, my problem stays @user3387542

Comment: Why don't you simply `source test.txt`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, the following Bash script should do the trick:

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS="="
while read k v ; do
    test -z "$k" && continue # skip empty lines
    declare $k=$v
done <test.txt

echo $Name
echo $Age
echo $Place
```

Why is that working? Most information can be retrieved from bash's man page:

- IFS is the "Internal Field Separator" which is used by bash's 'read' command to separate fields in each line. By default, IFS separates along spaces, but it is redefined to separate along the equal sign. It is a bash-only solution similar to the 'cut' command, where you define the equal sign as delimiter ('-d =').
- The 'read' builtin reads two fields from a line. As only two variables are provided (k and v), the first field ends up in k, all remaining fields (i.e. after the equal sign) end up in v.
- As the comment states, empty lines are skipped, i.e. those where the k variable is emtpy (test -z).
- 'eval' is a bash builtin as well, which executes the arguments (but only after evaluating $k=$v), i.e. the eval statement becomes equivalent to Name="ABC" etc.
- '<test.txt' after 'done' tells bash to read test.txt and to feed it line by line into the 'read' builtin further up.
- The three 'echo' statements are simply to show that this solution did work.

Comment: Don't use `eval` here. `declare "$k=$v"` does the same thing and more safely.

Comment: why is `eval` less safer ? @chepner

Comment: I think I know what @chepner means: 'eval' executes the argument one provides, so it is possible that $v could contain some Bash snipplet like `rm -rf /` (which gets executed!) for an input line like Age=`rm -rf /`. If 'declare' is used, it would simply assign the string `rm -rf /` to Age. Updating my solution ...

Answer (score 2):

The format or the file is valid sh syntax, so you could just source the file:

```
source test.txt
```

In any case, your code doesn't work because after the pipe you shouldn't specify the file again.

```
value1=$(grep -i 'Name' "$file" | cut -f2 -d'=')
```

would keep your logic

Comment: Nice observation about the format of the file. Reduces the solution to a single line, and blanks, comments, etc. embedded in the file won't cause problems.

Answer (score 2):

This is a comment, but the comment box does not allow formatting.  Consider rewriting this:

```
while read line; do
  value1=`grep -i 'Name' $file|cut -f2 -d'=' $file`
  value2=`grep -i 'Age' $file|cut -f2 -d'=' $file`
done <$file
```

as:

```
while IFS== read key value; do
  case $key in
  Name|name) value1=$value;;
  Age|age) value2=$value;;
  esac;
done < $file
```

Parsing the line multiple times via cut is inefficient.  This is slightly different than your version, since the comparison is case sensitive, but that is easily fixed if necessary.  For example, you could preprocess the input file and convert everything to lower case.  You can do the preprocessing on the fly, but be aware that this will put your while loop in a subprocess which will require some additional care (since the variable definitions will end with the pipeline), but that is not significant.  But running the entire file through grep twice for each line of the file is O(n^2), and ghastly!  (Why are you reading the entire file anyway instead of just echoing the line ?)

Comment: The code snippet that you have posted have multiple syntax errors. `while IFS== key value; do
  case $key in  # double quotes not necessary; no field splitting
  Name|name) value1="$value";;
  Age|age) value2="$value";;
done < $file` and after correcting those too ... it doesnt work.

Comment: @Subham Thank you for noticing the blatant errors, but I'm curious about your remark "it doesn't work".  I've corrected the errors, and this works quite well.

Comment: yeah i tried as i mentioned but i am afraid its not working for me!

Comment: Again, in what way is it not working?  Are you getting an error?  Or are you disturbed by the presence of double quotes in the strings?  Or ... something else?